# npm package not being bundle correct with webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, electron, node-modules, webpack-4

I'm attempting to use the `file-icon` node_module inside of a project where I am using electron & webpack.

When I use the package in a simple js file the module works fine (no bundler):

**my-file.js**

```
const fileIcon = require('file-icon');
const buffer = await fileIcon.buffer('path/to/some/file')
```

However, when I use this package with `webpack` to bundle all my javascript into 1 file, I get an error.

Observations:

1. The `file-icon` node_module directory looks this:

```
file-icon
├── file-icon <----this is a .bin executable
├── index.js
├── license
├── package.json
└── readme.md
```

When I put a breakpoint on the `fileIcon.buffer` method (*inside my codebase where webpack is used*)it is indeed defined, but the code breaks here where the `bin` variable gets defined with the wrong value. The bin doesn't include the `node_modules` folder anywhere in its path. Instead this points to the folder of my webpack bundle.

[image: webpack bundle requiring file-icon]

Comment: The best way is make upstream module changes to not use dynamic expression for path resolving. Webpack stats output may warn you already - webpack pre-evaluates paths to be included in bundle when import occurs, so any dynamic value expression in resolve path will cause possible failure to include those values cause webpack can't determine whereabouts of modules. Immdiate workaround would be specifying this module as externals and do not bundle it.

Comment: Thank you @OJKwon! Very thorough response. `externals:{file-icon': 'commonjs file-icon'}` solved my issue!